# Hide and call buttons

Tags: iphone, button, view, hide, slide

I have a camera view where the user can take pictures and do whatever they want with them. I am trying to keep my interface clean by not having so many buttons on screen.

I have a "back", "take picture", "select photo", and "save" button. Is there a way to hide these buttons? And be called whenever the user taps or slides something on the screen.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hide the button by using

```
button.hidden = YES;
```

If you want to show the button

```
button.hidden = NO;
```

For tap and slides(swipe) on the screen study about [UISwipeGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITapGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks so much. I guess that should work for now, until I perfected my app. This helps a lot.